# Compute the time it would take to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem for a graph with 12 vertices...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, hamiltonian-path

I need to compute the time it would take to solve the *Traveling Salesman Problem* for a graph with 12 vertices where it takes 10 minutes to compute the length of a single Hamilton Circuit.

> A Hamilton Circuit is a *circuit* that passes through every vertex **exactly** once.

Knowing the time it takes to compute the length of a single Hamilton Circuit, I need to determine how many years would it take to check *all* of the different circuits.

Comment: Easy – compute the number of different circuits, and multiply by 10.

Comment: Makes sense. That would give me the total number of minutes yes? So then convert that to years?

Comment: Sounds good to me.